# Changi's Free Singapore Tour - Can you leave early?

Tags: layovers, day-trips, sin

Changi offers a [free Singapore tour](http://www.changiairport.com/en/airport-experience/attractions-and-services/free-singapore-tour.html) and I'm interested in partaking.

However, I might also visit a friend for dinner before going back to the airport. Is it possible to defer from the itinerary of Changi's free tour?

I arrive at Singapore on 1:45pm, and my next flight is 6am the next day.

Comment: Hi @pnuts, see my answer. Sadly you have to return as a tour group. I'm not sure what the repercussions are of escaping though. I wouldn't risk it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I contacted Changi Airport's twitter account with the same question, and here is their response:

> Hi. If you join the free Singapore tour, you will have to adhere to
>   clear and re-enter immigration as a tour group. Hope this clarify.
>   Thanks.

So the answer is **NO**. You must be with the tour from start to finish, including the return to the airport.

Their email support says the same thing :

> We wish to inform that you are able to join the Free Singapore Tour
>   you are a transit passenger of Changi Airport, your layover period is
>   at least 5.5 hours and less than 24 hours, and your flight schedule
>   fits in with our tour timing requirements. You will need your
>   passport, boarding pass and a valid entry visa stipulated by the
>   Immigration & Checkpoints Authority of Singapore for registration. You
>   will not be able to divert away from the group if you want to join the
>   Free Singapore Tour as you will need to return to Changi Airport
>   together. For more information, you may visit
>   http://www.changiairport.com/en/airport-experience/attractions-and-services/free-singapore-tour.html.

Answer (score 3):

The free tour includes immigration checks, ie the group exits through Immigration as a group and returns to the airport through Immigration as a group.

Perhaps you can enter Singapore under your own citizenship rules as an individual, then hook up with the tour group as they exit. And later leave the tour group with the guide's permission.  But this is something you likely need to ask at Changi (or via email).

But entering Singapore as a visitor, may end your transit status thus causing you to be charged the departure tax.